# deleted subordinating conjunction - "dass"

Tags: sentence-structure, clauses

In English, it's written:

> He says (that) he'll come immediately.

In German it changes the sentence structure:

> Er sagt, dass er sofort kommt.

The problem is, if I delete "dass" from my sentence, then the sentence structure will be changed?

> Er sagt, er kommt sofort.

Am I allowed to write like English?

> *Er sagt, (dass) er kommt sofort.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. "Er sagt, er kommt sofort." is fine, "Er sagt, dass er kommt sofort." is not.

Comment: @Stefan Walter: I mean, If I delete "dass" from my sentence but there's still a deleted one (when reading the sentence you can add "dass") the sentence structure should be changed to normal ( subject, verb, ..) or it remains like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to say:

> Er sagt, er **komme** sofort.

or, more precisely:

> Er sagt, er **werde** sofort **kommen**.

Using "dass" is possible, too, but requires Konjunktiv I also:

> Er sagt, **dass** er sofort **komme**.

"[Indirect speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech)" requires the usage of "Konjunktiv I" in german: [Indirekte Rede bei canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html). But in everyday speech, Konjunktiv is used rarely. You will hear "Er sagt, er **kommt** gleich" or "Er sagt, dass er gleich **kommt**." quite commonly.