# Wortstellung mit 'glauben'

Tags: word-order

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   ["Ich denke, das ist keine schlechte Idee" or "Ich denke, dass das keine schlechte Idee ist"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20092/ich-denke-das-ist-keine-schlechte-idee-or-ich-denke-dass-das-keine-schlecht)

Aus [einem Artikel von "German is Easy"](https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/gleich-sofort-nachher-bald-spater/)

> Ich glaube mein Handy geht bald kaputt.

Ich denke, dass der Satz so geschrieben werden soll:

> Ich glaube, dass mein Handy bald kaputt geht.

Wenn das zweite Beispiel richtig ist, ist das erste umgangssprachlich?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Ich weiß es erscheint seltsam" - is the word order correct?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17374/ich-wei%c3%9f-es-erscheint-seltsam-is-the-word-order-correct)

Comment: Also strongly related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/deleted-subordinating-conjunction-dass/1728#1728

Comment: Actually, this one is probably the best match: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/is-the-sub-clause-in-my-book-correct/8857#8857

Comment: The second one is the proper construction, however I hear native German speakers use the first construction frequently. I would like to know if the first is downright incorrect or if it is simply used for speed or another reason.

Comment: @Dustin... they're both equally correct and the first one is preferable. See the related answers for details

Comment: The first one is preferable? Ich glaub', mein Schwein pfeift!

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... you don't think so? I guess I should say that I'm talking about spoken German.

Comment: That was my initial reaction, and I was trying to be clever ;) Indeed, I think that the two have slightly different meaning/emphasis, but I will leave that for an answer for which I do not have the time right now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kurze Antwort: Viele Wege führen nach Rom. Beide Sätze sind vollkommen in Ordnung. Nur hinter "ich glaube" gehört im ersten Satz ein Komma, der die 2 Teilsätze voneinander trennt.

Answer (score 2):

Der Nebensatz „dass mein Handy bald kaputt geht“ ist ein Inhaltssatz.

Die Konstruktion mit der Konjunktion „dass“ + Endstellung des Finitums (hier: „geht“) ist sicherlich die wichtigste Möglichkeit, einen Inhaltssatz an einen Hauptsatz anzuschließen:

> Sie sagte, dass sie später komme.
>
> Ich glaube, dass mein Handy bald kaputt geht.

Darüber hinaus gibt es allerdings noch einige andere mögliche Konstruktionen. (In *Duden – Die Grammatik* werden insgesamt zehn verschiedene Anschlussmerkmale für Inhaltssätze aufgeführt, von denen allerdings die meisten nicht zusammen mit „glauben“ verwendet werden können.)

Insbesondere bei indirekter Rede oder Gedanken kann auch ein Satz mit Finitum in Zweitstellung als Inhaltssatz an einen Hauptsatz angeschlossen werden:

> Sie sagte, sie komme später.
>
> Ich glaube, mein Handy geht bald kaputt.

Gemäß § 74 des amtlichen Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung muss in jedem Fall der Nebensatz vom Hauptsatz mit Komma abgegrenzt werden.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Es ist zwar hilfreich, aber zu schwierig für einen Anfänger wie mich. Ich übersetze noch!

Answer (score 1):

Both variants are correct. Nowadays the first is generally considered more elegant and easier to read. However, one or two centuries ago it may have been colloquial. More importantly, even now the first variant would be wrong with most other verbs instead of *glauben*. I believe the criterion is very roughly that the subordinate clause should be indirect speech (so the verb in the main clause could also be *denken*, *sagen*, ...), though you shouldn't rely on this and should instead find somewhere to look up the actual rule if you want to use this construction.

All Germanic languages are in the process of switching from the original proto-Germanic word order (free with a preference for SOV) to the modern SVO word order. English has reached SVO with only a few remnants of SOV. German is still in an intermediate stage in which normal main clauses are an odd approximation to SVO (known as V2 because the finite verb comes in second position) and normal subordinate clauses still have SOV word order. This causes indirect speech to have an unnatural word order (different from that of direct speech), and it appears that this problem has become a motor of word order modernisation.

I think the best approach for English speakers learning German is to not use it initially; understanding it won't be a problem anyway. By reading a lot of German you will automatically acquire a good intuition for using or avoiding the construction as appropriate.