# "Ich denke, das ist keine schlechte Idee" or "Ich denke, dass das keine schlechte Idee ist"

Tags: usage, sentence-structure

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   [Wortstellung mit 'glauben'](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/wortstellung-mit-glauben)

This is a question for the native speakers. What do you think is mostly used between these two sentences?

> Ich denke, das ist keine schlechte Idee.
>   Ich denke, dass das keine schlechte Idee ist.

What would you say? Are they anyways both correct?

Comment: Related: [Wortstellung mit 'glauben'](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/wortstellung-mit-glauben)

Comment: There is community consent that we should not close dupes to questions in different language: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct and both have exactly the same meaning. I would probably use the first (shorter) version, but I would not be irritated at all if somebody uses the second one; it is also idiomatic.

Comment: Gut feeling: Version 1. Might be a regional thing...

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the variant with "dass" in written German. Actually, this is a form of indirect speech, as something is repeated which is not a real event: the content of your thoughts. If it would be "ich dachte", then Konjunktiv would be used, either I or II.

Comment: Der Konjunktiv käme mir unnatürlich vor.

Answer (score -1):

In spoken language variant 1 is preferred. As a general rule you can say that when there is a shorter version the shorter one is preferred.

Comment: Can you give a source for the claim, that shorter versions are preferred or is this just a guess, or maybe a wish of you?

Comment: I have no source. It's an observation of mine. People say "Guten Morgen", and not "Ich wünsche Ihnen einen guten Morgen". They even say "Morgen" or "Morn".

Comment: Und wieso sagen sie "zeitnah" und nicht "flugs", "bald" oder "gleich"? Kann man solch einzelne Beobachtungen einfach so verallgemeinern?

Comment: Hat der Gebrauch von Varianten etwas mit der ursprünglichen Frage zu tun? - Das sind keine Einzelfälle. Ķürzungen sind eine häufige Erscheinung in allen Sprachen, weil Sprechen Artikulationsarbeit ist und weil wir mit einer bestimmten Geschwindigkeit denken. Und die Geschwindigkeit des Sprechens muß der des Denkens einigermaßen angepaßt sein. Grammatiken haben noch nicht so richtig erkannt, dass Ķürzungen ein wichtiges und großes Kapitel der Sprachbeschreibung wäre. Aber mit Kürzungen kann man in jeder Sprache ein Buch füllen.

Comment: Tja, und was morgens gekürzt wird, wird nachmittags wieder durch umständliche Formeln aufgefüllt und verlängert, durch Wiederholung des Gesagten, durch teilweise Rücknahme und mit Floskeln wird es aufgeblasen.